# SystemProperties.set not working

Tags: android, system-properties

I have following code in my Source code to set SystemProperties.

```
        SystemProperties.set("ro.csc.countryiso_code","KoreaA");

        String country1 = SystemProperties.get("ro.csc.countryiso_code");

        Log.e("DebugA",country1);
        SystemProperties.set("ro.csc.countryiso_code","KoreaB");
        String country2 = SystemProperties.get("ro.csc.countryiso_code");

        Log.e("DebugB",country2);
```

`

Why am i not getting Second Change to SystemProperties?
**But in LogCat Debug I am always getting :-
:- DebugA KoreaA
:- DebugB KoreaA**
Is it only the once we can set SystemProperties from our Code and that will persist for ever until device is switched off and turned on again?

As i checked changing after switching off my device and turning it on again :-

I have following code in my Source code to set SystemProperties.

```
        SystemProperties.set("ro.csc.countryiso_code","KoreaB");

        String country1 = SystemProperties.get("ro.csc.countryiso_code");

        Log.e("DebugA",country1);
        SystemProperties.set("ro.csc.countryiso_code","KoreaA");
        String country2 = SystemProperties.get("ro.csc.countryiso_code");

        Log.e("DebugB",country2);
```

**And in LogCat Debug I am always getting :-
:- DebugA KoreaB
:- DebugB KoreaB**

Comment: I'm not that familiar with `SystemProperties`, but why aren't you using `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: Do use SharedPref. For better approach

Comment: That is Okay.. I am asking can we change it using SystemProperties. If so how Can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
     SystemProperties.set("ro.csc.countryiso_code","KoreaA");
```

The name of the property starts with "ro", means it's a read-only property, so once set, you can't change it any more.

Comment: can it be changed by the OS itself?

Comment: System apps can't change "ro" property either. Use "persist" instead.  @ParthSrivastav